# Object from 2 classes

Tags: swift

I have a class `Admin` and a class `SecurityGuard`. I would like to create a `securitySupervisor` object that can access both the Admin and SecurityGuard methods. I don't want to make a third class (for various obvious reasons such as ease of future changes.) Is there a way to let one object use the methods from two, unrelated classes?

Thank you.

Comment: Made a protocol that both classes conform to?

Comment: I was reading about protocols and thought that may be the answer, but I'm not certain how to go about it.

Comment: Please give an example method for `securitySupervisor` for better understanding what you would like to achieve. Do you want an object without a specific class that has all the methods from Admin and SecurityGuard? What if they both have name() method, what result do you expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use two protocols and implement them in one class. Here's a simplified example to get you going.

```
protocol Admin {
  var isAdmin: Bool { get }
}

protocol SecurityGuard {
  func protect()
}

class SecuritySupervisor: Admin, SecurityGuard {
  var isAdmin = true

  func protect() {
    print("You're protected")
  }
}

let securitySupervisor = SecuritySupervisor()
securitySupervisor.isAdmin   // true
securitySupervisor.protect() // prints "You're protected"
```

Also keep in mind that protocols can have default implementations which is useful if you want the same implementation in more than one class:

```
protocol Admin {
  var isAdmin: Bool { get }
}

protocol SecurityGuard {
  func protect()
}

extension SecurityGuard {
  func protect() {
    print("You're protected")
  }
}

class SecuritySupervisor: Admin, SecurityGuard {
  var isAdmin = true
}

class NormalGuard: SecurityGuard {}

let securitySupervisor = SecuritySupervisor()
securitySupervisor.isAdmin
// works like before
securitySupervisor.protect()
// same implementation
NormalGuard().protect()
```

Comment: Very nice examples. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Multiple inheritance in Swift is achieved using protocols. Any arbitrary type may be declared as conforming to a protocol, so long as it provides the requirements specified by that protocol.

```
protocol Admin {
    func administer()
}
protocol SecurityGuard {
    func guardSecurity()
}
```

To reduce code duplication, protocol extensions may be used to add functionality to all types conforming to the protocol, including providing default implementations for the protocol's requirements:

```
extension Admin {
    func administer() { print("Administering") }
}
extension SecurityGuard {
    func guardSecurity() { print("Guarding Security") }
}

// Declaring conformance to the protocols is all that is required.
class BusyPerson: Admin, SecurityGuard {
    init() { }
}
BusyPerson().administer()
BusyPerson().guardSecurity()
```

Comment: It is possible solution, but I don´t know how it fits the specs. It could force you to have a lot of the Admin class logic in the extension. For sure it works.

Answer (score 0):

A very, very simple solution would be:

```
import Foundation

        class SecurityGuard
        {
            func securityFunc() { }
        }

        class Admin
        {
            func adminFunc() { }
        }

        class SecuritySupervisor
        {
            let securityGuard: SecurityGuard
            let admin: Admin

            init()
            {
                self.admin = Admin()
                self.securityGuard = SecurityGuard()
            }
        }

    SecuritySupervisor().securityGuard.securityFunc()
    SecuritySupervisor().admin.adminFunc()
```

Comment: This is called composition (has-a relation) instead of inheritance (is-a relation). The OP states "I don't want to make a third class", but this is also a clean and valid solution.

Comment: The same thing when the specs says: "I would like to create a securitySupervisor object that can access both the Admin and SecurityGuard methods.", By doing this using extensions you don't have the logic in the class.